# How to put a web part from one site to another in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

There are two SharePoint sites, each based on its own SharePoint installation.

Both are in the same domain.

The first site is for a document flow.

The second site is for a knowledge base.

I need to put a set of web parts (search, search results, indexed document library) from the second site in the master page of the first site.

The services and data will stay on the second site but they would be available in the first site.

I tried to apply the Page Viewer Web Part but it’s impossible to avoid using the second site’s master page layout.

**Question**

What other ways exist to solve this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can index content of first SharePoint farm with search service application in another SharePoint farm.
You should configure search service application and add new website content source in search service application setting.
In this scenario you dose not need to move any thing and SharePoint crawl your content periodically.

Comment: Yes, but if the set has not only searching web parts, actually I need to relocate the set of three web parts - search, search results, doc library (I had edited my question extending the web part list). In any way, thanks for your answer, because it was my mind restriction that searching available within only its own farm.